# Java: How can I write HashMap <String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> to a file?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

So i am able to write:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> ...
```

but When it comes to a structure like

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> ...
```

I fail...

```
Set<String> keys = outer.keySet();
List<String> list = sortList(keys);
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> inner=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String key = it.next();
                    Set<Integer> ids= inner.keySet();
                    List<Integer> positions=sortList(ids);
                    Iterator<Integer> itIn=positions.iterator();
                    while(itIn.hasNext()){
                        String id= it.next();
                        output.write(key + "\t" + outer.get(key) + " " +inner.get(id) +"\n");
                    }
                }
```

My code can write all the keys outer has, and first elements of the Integer1 but can not see list or so on.
How can I make a connection with inner hashmap and outer hashmap?

Comment: Are you sure you really meant to write this code? Look at the `inner` variable, you are instantiating it right now, and you want to iterate over it? That collection is empty, so there can't be no values inside it.

Comment: I dont meant to, it is the best crude idea i had. yes, i could not figure out how to integrate the outer values to the inner

Comment: Then stop thinking about hashmaps, arraylists and on, and start thinking as a matrix. What you have over there? A really special map. You map Srings into Integer and then into Integer again. So, thinking in a 3D matrix, we Have Matrix[String][Integer][Integer]. Try this approach if you can think up with a better solution. But this really looks like an error in the approach. Think as a 3D matrix and you'll get it. I've successfully made an idea to serialize a 3D Matrix, but while using your `HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>` things got really complicated.

Comment: Upvoted for you do your own try first. If you fail, please tell me again so I can show you a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about storing the whole object as a file via [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)? Something like:

```
public static void saveObject(HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> obj, String filePath)
{
    OutputStream os = null;
    try
    {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        os.writeObject(obj);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    finally
    {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Then you can load it like:

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> loadObject(String filePath)
{
    HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> obj = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        obj = (HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>) is.readObject();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    finally
    {
        is.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Note that you need to implement the `Serializable` interface to use this object serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the `inner` variable, it will take care of serializing all the references it holds inside.

As an aside note, why would you need such a nested data structure? it smells like a design problem.

Comment: I am storing, position indexes and file id's for each unique word within a big dataset. To do that, i thought this way would be nicer.

Comment: But surely you could have simplified the design somehow, what you're creating is a maintainability headache